# How to install mysql udf in windows WAMP

Tags: mysql, wamp

How to install `MySQL udf` in `WAMP`. I am using this https://code.google.com/p/mysql-udf-http/ It have instruction for Linux but not for windows, How do I install it in MySQL in `WAMP`. I have downloaded this and executed the `.sh` file but nothing happens. I am trying to install it to call php pages inside mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you read this?  [Install instructions](https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_str/blob/master/README.win_x86.txt) It all seems fairly straight forward as long as you remember your mysql lives under the `\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.x.y` folder and not in the default locations mentioned in the instructions.

If you dont think they are simple enough, what are you having a problem with?

Comment: how to create dll library from it?

Comment: I saw somewhere that you could download a pre compiled dll. But I cannot find it again. You need to do some searching for a pre compiled dll.